# better performance in an Excel UDF with IF or Select Case

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I need often to search in Excel with formulas for some special texts in a cell. The number of rows i need to search are 100.000 to 500.000, in rare case up to 1.000.000. To avoid long formulas i wrote a own UDF to search for multiple text strings in a cell. The new formula is short to handle. I optimize the runtime of this formula as good as i can. It needs 11 to 12 sec for 500.000 rows.

I made this formula in two ways: one uses IF-Statement (SuchenSIF), the other (SuchenSSELCASE) use SELECT CASE Statements. Booth formulas have the same speed. Can you give me some hint how to get a better performance?

*Syntax of this formula is:*
SuchenSIF(cell to search, text to search 1, ... text to search 6)
SuchenSSELCASE(cell to search, text to search 1, ... text to search 6)

```
Public Function SuchenSIF(Zelle As Range, such1 As String, Optional such2 As String, Optional such3 As String, Optional such4 As String, Optional such5 As String, Optional such6 As String) As Integer
Application.Volatile

' this code, based on IF-statements need 11-12 seconds for 500.000 rows
' Start of IF-Section
'
ZelleWert = Zelle.Value
SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such1, vbTextCompare)
If SuchenS > 0 Then Exit Function
SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such2, vbTextCompare)
If SuchenS <> vbFalse Then Exit Function
If Len(such3) > 0 Then
    SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such3, vbTextCompare)
    If SuchenS > 0 Then Exit Function
    If Len(such4) > 0 Then
        SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such4, vbTextCompare)
        If SuchenS > 0 Then Exit Function
        If Len(such5) > 0 Then
            SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such5, vbTextCompare)
            If SuchenS > 0 Then Exit Function
            If Len(such6) > 0 Then
                SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such6, vbTextCompare)
                If SuchenS > 0 Then Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
'
' End of IF-Section
If SuchenS = 0 Then SuchenS = False
End Function

Public Function SuchenSSELCASE(Zelle As Range, such1 As String, Optional such2 As String, Optional such3 As String, Optional such4 As String, Optional such5 As String, Optional such6 As String) As Integer
Application.Volatile
' this code, based on SELECT-CASE-statements need 11-12 seconds for 500.000 rows
' Start of SELECT-CASE -Section
'
ZelleWert = Zelle.Value
SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such1, vbTextCompare) * Len(such1)
Select Case SuchenS
    Case 0
        SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such2, vbTextCompare) * Len(such2)
        Select Case SuchenS
            Case 0
                SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such3, vbTextCompare) * Len (such3)
                Select Case SuchenS
                    Case 0
                        SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such4, vbTextCompare) * Len(such4)
                        Select Case SuchenS
                            Case 0
                                SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such5, vbTextCompare) * Len(such5)
                                Select Case SuchenS
                                    Case 0
                                        SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, such6, vbTextCompare) * Len(such6)
                                        Select Case SuchenS
                                            Case 0
                                            Case Else
                                                SuchenS = SuchenS / Len(such6)
                                                Exit Function
                                        End Select
                                    Case Else
                                        SuchenS = SuchenS / Len(such5)
                                        Exit Function
                                End Select
                            Case Else
                                SuchenS = SuchenS / Len(such4)
                                Exit Function
                        End Select
                    Case Else
                        SuchenS = SuchenS / Len(such3)
                        Exit Function
                End Select
            Case Else
                SuchenS = SuchenS / Len(such2)
                Exit Function
        End Select
    Case Else
        SuchenS = SuchenS / Len(such1)
        Exit Function
End Select
'
' End of SELECT-CASE -Section
If SuchenS = 0 Then SuchenS = False
End Function
```

Comment: are you calling this `Function` from a VBS `Sub` ? or from a cell in a sheet ?

Comment: i call this from a cell in a sheet

Comment: @Enrico, if this is working code you should take this question over to Code Review - they're great over there

Comment: Why have you made the function volatile? It doesn't appear to need it. `vbTextCompare` is slower than converting the values to the same case.

Comment: I would recommend trying Excel Formula instead. VBA is limited to one thread, but Excel formulas can be calculated in parallel https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687899.aspx

Comment: @Rory Function `Volatile` is from testing there, it is not needed, thats right.  Replace `vbTextCompare` with UCase save 1-2 seconds. Thank you.

Comment: @Slai The users work currently with formulas. These formulas are up to 5 lines long and bad to maintain (searched word need to get replaced). This new formula will make it a bit better maintainable.

Comment: @Enrico The way to do this using formulas is to have a series of 6 formulas in consecutive cells, each returning `TRUE`/`FALSE` and then a final `AND()` formula to give you your result. It will be quick, simple, extendable, threaded, and won't open up all the problems associated with using VBA.

Comment: @Enrico See [Example](http://imgur.com/a/yPkEM), [Example with formulas](http://imgur.com/a/MGIff)

Comment: @Kaz Thank you. But we discuss every column we add. The files have size up to 300MB in xlsx (or 70MB in xlsb) and we are on the the limit what Excel can handle. So 6 additional columns are not an option. This formula is even a way to reduce file size and make it easier for Excel to handle it.

Comment: @Enrico I'm sure this has been noted already, but when you have 300MB spreadsheets that are *anything other* than raw data, you have more fundamental problems.

Comment: @emrico Speaking from experience, if your spreadsheets get much bigger, or your VBA isn't *very* carefully targeted, your application will crash simply for running out of memory.

Comment: @Kaz Yes, youre right, without doubt. This is a temporarly solution to find out a system of tracking data quality. If we know what we will track, this all has an end and is programmed as database and regulary analyze. Excel is just the tool for 'prototyping'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make some speed gains by converting the cell value to a string once before all the instr calls rather than forcing a variant to string conversion for each call.

```
Dim ZelleWert as string
ZelleWert=Cstr(Zelle.Value2)
```

If you have a large number of calls to the UDF you need to avoid the VBE Refresh bug: see https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-3-avoiding-the-vbe-refresh-bug/

And you could probably make a faster UDF if you converted the UDF to handle a Range of cells and return an array of results: see 
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/writing-efiicient-vba-udfs-part5-udf-array-formulas-go-faster/

Comment: Thank you Charles, especially the links are very helpful and interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any data how you use this `Function` and what you are trying to achieve. Maybe we can replace your entire `Function` concept with something shorter and faster.

**Edit**: removed the previous concept, and decided to use this version with `Application.Match`.

```
Public Function SuchenSIF(Zelle As Range, such1 As String, Optional such2 As String, Optional such3 As String, Optional such4 As String, Optional such5 As String, Optional such6 As String) As Integer
        
    Dim suchArr() As String, Elem As Variant

    ReDim suchArr(0 To 5)

    ' create suchArr with only such arguments that are none-blank
    For Each Elem In Array(such1, such2, such3, such4, such5, such6)
        If Elem <> vbNullString Then
            suchArr(i) = Elem
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Elem
    
    ReDim Preserve suchArr(0 To i - 1) ' resize to actual populated array size
    
    ' use Match to get the index of the array that is matched
    SuchenSIF = Application.Match(Zelle.Value, suchArr, 0) - 1
    
    If IsError(SuchenSIF) Then SuchenSIF = -10000  ' Just to Raise some kind of error "NOT found!"
           
End Function
```

Comment: I think that code will run slower because it does multiple calls to Range.Value and each call is expensive.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams thanks, updated. I wroteit too fast (my braind didn't catch-up) :)

Comment: @ShaiRado, where are you returning the value to the function?

Comment: @CallumDA I just added the section that can be replaced to shorten the run-time a bit, not replaced the PO entire code

Comment: @ShaiRado, all I'm saying is that you couldn't replace those two sections of code with each other, because OP is explicitly setting the value of the function `SuchenS` each time, so an `Exit Function` would return that value, whereas your `Exit Function`s would result in `0` being returned every time

Comment: @CallumDA but the name of his `Function` is `SuchenSIF`, not  `SuchenS` (at least according to his posted code)

Comment: @ShaiRado, I think OP renamed his functions as an afterthought - otherwise they wouldn't be "working" as OP suggests they are

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array containing only the parameters which have been passed to the function and loop through that for a bit of a speed gain (...I think)

```
Public Function SuchenSIF(Zelle As Range, such1 As String, Optional such2 As String, Optional such3 As String, Optional such4 As String, Optional such5 As String, Optional such6 As String) As Integer
    Application.Volatile

    Dim possibleInputs As Variant, v As Variant, inputs As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ZelleWert As String

    possibleInputs = Array(such2, such3, such4, such5, such6)

    'create an array of non-empty parameters
    ReDim inputs(0 To 0)
    inputs(0) = such1
    For i = 0 To 4
        If possibleInputs(i) <> vbNullString Then
            ReDim Preserve inputs(0 To UBound(inputs) + 1)
            inputs(UBound(inputs)) = possibleInputs(i)
        End If
    Next i

    ZelleWert = CStr(Zelle.Value)

    'loop through given parameters and exit if found
    For Each v In inputs
        SuchenS = InStr(1, ZelleWert, v, vbTextCompare)
        If SuchenS > 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next v
End Function
```

Comment: Instead of looping thourgh `inputs` , you could use the `Application.Match` and eliminate the looping

Comment: @ShaiRado not sure if I've understood correctly but if OP is looking for `string` from `a string like this` then match wouldn't work. And your solution would need wildcards, but I might be mistaken :/

Comment: See my **EDITED** answer below, on to use `Application.Match` instead of looping

Comment: @ShaiRado, I still don't understand. If Zella.Value = "abcde" and the array contains {"b","z"} the match won't return anything? But InStr will.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think of the possibility the PO wants to look for partial text in a Cell. If he is looking for exact match, it will work ;)

Comment: @Shai Rado  I need to find partial text, yes. But thank you for your suggetions. They was helpful too.